# In R, how to construct vectors of the corresponding elements of the data frames

Tags: r, arrays, list, dataframe

I have a list of data frames, for example the first three

```
[[1]]
01oct 24sep 17sep 10sep 03sep 27aug 20aug 13aug 06aug 30jul 23jul 16jul 09jul 02jul 25jun 18jun 11jun 04jun 28may 21may 14may 07may 30apr 23apr 
 3.25  9.50  0.80  6.85  6.70  6.65 14.35 62.35  9.75  2.35 18.55  8.90 17.85 14.75  0.90  0.50 17.05 19.15 44.25  0.15 42.05 10.45 12.00  5.05 
16apr 09apr 02apr 
 0.15 12.90 23.20 

[[2]]
30sep 23sep 16sep 09sep 02sep 26aug 19aug 12aug 05aug 29jul 22jul 15jul 08jul 01jul 24jun 17jun 10jun 03jun 27may 20may 13may 06may 29apr 22apr 
 1.90  4.60 23.95  3.95 12.65 26.30 38.30  2.80  2.35 34.10  8.30  7.30 28.85  2.45  5.20 15.35  1.85 36.75  0.95  8.40 22.35 37.70  6.00  0.40 
15apr 08apr 
 3.25  5.45 

[[3]]
28sep 21sep 14sep 07sep 31aug 24aug 17aug 10aug 03aug 27jul 20jul 13jul 06jul 29jun 22jun 15jun 08jun 01jun 25may 18may 11may 04may 27apr 20apr 
 5.85 13.70  2.85 12.50 43.40 13.25  5.65  4.80 12.20  5.40  3.05 12.90 20.70 21.75 13.20 18.60  0.70 13.15 20.30  2.40  2.30 13.50  4.70 19.60 
13apr 06apr 
17.60 14.50
```

I am trying to create vectors of the corresponding elements of each data frame. In the above example, the first three elements of my first vector would be 3.25, 1.90, 5.85. The second vector would be 9.5, 4.6, 13.7. The strings showing dates ideally would be left out, since at a later stage the vectors will be used to compute correlations.
My ultimate goal is an array of these vectors.

I know this could be done with a nested loops, however I've tried and have other problems with this kind of array assignment in R (but that's for another thread). I also know that nested loops are inefficient and not best practice (at least I understood that).

What is the most reproducible way to construct these vectors and the array of them in R?

Comment: Can you please provide the example data as the output of `dput`, then it's easier to help you, thanks! Do you want to construct single vectors or store the vectors in a list (which would be easier)?

Comment: Du you really want to combine 01oct with 30sep to get (3.25, 1.90)? the values were mesured at differnt dates...

Comment: That's not a list of frames, it's a list of named vectors. Are you *supposed* to have frames and somehow lost the structure on a previous step?

Comment: *"dates ideally would be left out ... compute correlations"* seems wrong, for two reasons: (1) `cor` doesn't care about the names of the numeric vectors, it just computes, so they are at worst a distraction; and (2) I don't know how you intend to calculate correlation, you have differing lengths of vectors here, `cor` needs equal-length vectors.

Comment: Hey @r2evans I didn't explain properly, I will calculate the correlation between the output vectors and another parameter that has a value for each year of seven. Apologies.

Comment: @danlooo True, for now I'm going to work with the data element wise, i.e corresponding values, or 'relative' time, if you like. I plan to compare this with some standardized date system if I have the time.

Comment: @r2evans RE. The first question you asked about losing the structure of my original data frames - now I see a bit late why this is a problem, because I can't retrieve the dates in the named objects using 'colnames' and 'rownames'

Comment: Neither `colnames` nor `rownames` will return names for something that is neither a `data.frame` nor a `matrix`; the `names` function is used for named vectors/lists.

Comment: Is there a way to use the names function as an argument to functions of the apply family when you have an object that is a list of named vectors and you want to use lapply (or one of it's family) to take the name of each vector. It makes sense to me that names(object) can't be used but if not then how can the names function be worked with

Comment: To be precise my 'object' is a list of lists, eg `[[7]][[17]]
16sep 09sep 02sep 
 1.05 17.00 40.20`

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)

# example data
l <- list(
  data.frame(a = 3.25, b = 9.5),
  data.frame(c = 1.90, d = 4.6),
  data.frame(e = 5.85, d = 13.70)
)

combined <-
  l %>%
  map(~ {
    # unify column names
    colnames(.x) <- colnames(.x) %>% length() %>% seq()
    .x
  }) %>%
  reduce(bind_rows)

combined[[1]]
#> [1] 3.25 1.90 5.85
combined[[2]]
#> [1]  9.5  4.6 13.7
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a transposition of the vectors. This is going to run into problems, because to do so suggests that the vectors should all be the same length, which they're not.

```r
lengths(yourlist)
# [1] 27 26 26
```

We can fix that by padding them with `NA`,

```r
yourlist <- lapply(yourlist, `length<-`, max(lengths(yourlist)))

yourlist
# [[1]]
# 01oct 24sep 17sep 10sep 03sep 27aug 20aug 13aug 06aug 30jul 23jul 16jul 09jul 02jul 25jun 18jun 11jun 04jun 28may 21may 14may 07may 30apr 23apr 16apr 09apr 02apr 
#  3.25  9.50  0.80  6.85  6.70  6.65 14.35 62.35  9.75  2.35 18.55  8.90 17.85 14.75  0.90  0.50 17.05 19.15 44.25  0.15 42.05 10.45 12.00  5.05  0.15 12.90 23.20 
# [[2]]
# 30sep 23sep 16sep 09sep 02sep 26aug 19aug 12aug 05aug 29jul 22jul 15jul 08jul 01jul 24jun 17jun 10jun 03jun 27may 20may 13may 06may 29apr 22apr 15apr 08apr       
#  1.90  4.60 23.95  3.95 12.65 26.30 38.30  2.80  2.35 34.10  8.30  7.30 28.85  2.45  5.20 15.35  1.85 36.75  0.95  8.40 22.35 37.70  6.00  0.40  3.25  5.45    NA 
# [[3]]
# 28sep 21sep 14sep 07sep 31aug 24aug 17aug 10aug 03aug 27jul 20jul 13jul 06jul 29jun 22jun 15jun 08jun 01jun 25may 18may 11may 04may 27apr 20apr 13apr 06apr       
#  5.85 13.70  2.85 12.50 43.40 13.25  5.65  4.80 12.20  5.40  3.05 12.90 20.70 21.75 13.20 18.60  0.70 13.15 20.30  2.40  2.30 13.50  4.70 19.60 17.60 14.50    NA
```

Given that, a list-transpose:

```r
yourlist2 <- do.call(Map, c(list(f = c, use.names = FALSE), yourlist))
str(yourlist2)
# List of 27
#  $ : num [1:3] 3.25 1.9 5.85
#  $ : num [1:3] 9.5 4.6 13.7
#  $ : num [1:3] 0.8 23.95 2.85
#  $ : num [1:3] 6.85 3.95 12.5
#  $ : num [1:3] 6.7 12.6 43.4
#  $ : num [1:3] 6.65 26.3 13.25
#  $ : num [1:3] 14.35 38.3 5.65
#  $ : num [1:3] 62.4 2.8 4.8
#  $ : num [1:3] 9.75 2.35 12.2
#  $ : num [1:3] 2.35 34.1 5.4
#  $ : num [1:3] 18.55 8.3 3.05
#  $ : num [1:3] 8.9 7.3 12.9
#  $ : num [1:3] 17.9 28.9 20.7
#  $ : num [1:3] 14.75 2.45 21.75
#  $ : num [1:3] 0.9 5.2 13.2
#  $ : num [1:3] 0.5 15.3 18.6
#  $ : num [1:3] 17.05 1.85 0.7
#  $ : num [1:3] 19.1 36.8 13.2
#  $ : num [1:3] 44.25 0.95 20.3
#  $ : num [1:3] 0.15 8.4 2.4
#  $ : num [1:3] 42 22.4 2.3
#  $ : num [1:3] 10.4 37.7 13.5
#  $ : num [1:3] 12 6 4.7
#  $ : num [1:3] 5.05 0.4 19.6
#  $ : num [1:3] 0.15 3.25 17.6
#  $ : num [1:3] 12.9 5.45 14.5
#  $ : num [1:3] 23.2 NA NA
```

Comment: So in the above, the line f = c, is c a shorthand for a column?

Comment: No. The first argument for the function `Map` is `f=`, a function that accepts one or more arguments. The `c` is the base R function `base::c`, the concatenation function.

Comment: A way to think about this maybe is using c() to create a vector and 'Map' to apply that to the rest of the named vector by association? Or maybe that's why do.call is required... I suspected that Map was the method I wanted, but wasn't sure how to use it. This also gives me motivation to learn do.call in R. Nice example. Thanks

Comment: `Map` is "zipping" all of the data together. The first time `c` is called, it is called with the first elem of each of the lists, aka `c(3.25, 1.9, 5.85)`; the second time `c` is called, it is called with the second elem of each of the lists, `c(9.5, 4.6, 13.7)`; etc. Similar to `lapply`, it always returns a list, so the first element in the list is the first `c(..)` I just posted. `Map` itself can be confusing, and abstracting it with `do.call` makes it a little more difficult, but ... the use of `do.call` makes it trivial to apply it to arbitrary arguments (i.e., `length(yourlist)`, unk)